# Gerund for Curious

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a gerund, a noun formed from a verb by adding ing, that can communicate the idea of being curious.  It's stupid, so please don't make me explain why I need this.

Words like 'understanding,' 'exploring,' and 'collaborating' are insufficient.

Comment: Well the starting problem is that "curious" is not a verb but an adjective. The noun formed from that root is of course "curiosity".

Comment: This is a single word request. It will help answerers immensely if you  include:
A sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used, 
What thesaurus or dictionary searches you've tried, 
Clear criteria for choosing the "best" word (e.g. register, connotations, part of speech), 
What words you've considered, and why they don't work for you, 
Whether a compound word or phrase would be acceptable

Comment: inquiring but I be hard pressed to actually use it as a noun. I think context here is vital.

Comment: For inappropriate curiosity you might like "prying".

Answer (score 0):

First, we must agree that ***curious*** is an adjective that is not normally verbalised, so it cannot be used as a Gerund. There are however verbs that can mean *to feel curious*, and they can take the -ing inflectional ending. The best choice is ***wondering***:

***Wonder*** can be both intransitive:

> to feel curiosity or doubt
>
> - ***wondering*** about the future

and intransitive:

> to be curious or in doubt about
>
> - he ***wonders*** why birds sing ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wonder))

Answer (score 0):

**inquiring**

> adjective   (*British* enquiring)
> Showing an interest in learning new things. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/inquiring)

> **inquire** Transitive verb
> 2: to search into : INVESTIGATE [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inquiring)

> *curiousness*
> 2. Curiosity; inquisitiveness
> 3. A curious or **inquiring** disposition [*An American Dictionary*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_American_Encyclopaedic_Dictionary/CjUjB3D2WNwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=curious%20inquiring&pg=PA1231&printsec=frontcover). (1894)

> *The **Inquiring** Mind* [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Inquiring_Mind/lCmQDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the%20inquiring%20mind%22&printsec=frontcover).

> *Physics for the **Inquiring** Mind* [ref](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the%20inquiring%20mind%22).

> *Confessions of an **Inquiring** Spirit* [ref](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22inquiring%20spirit%22&biw=904&bih=497&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03_H-SVfWIEKM69ZMsGj9hckI9j8g%3A1628874203999&ei=26UWYZmePMWStAa11KdQ&oq=%22inquiring%20spirit%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...17493.19674.0.20125.7.7.0.0.0.0.74.486.7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.284...33i299k1j33i10k1.0.g6JR6e9o_xg).

> The self-discipline of note-taking can be an important part of
> developing an “**inquiring** attitude.” [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Principles_and_Methods_of_Transformative/Ce4fEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22inquiring%20attitude%22&pg=PA78&printsec=frontcover).